# How to remove the last 13 (or n) characters of every line using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file which each line that ends with `Mar 15, 2013` and other dates so I need to remove the end of each line say the last 13 characters

Each line is a different length and has different characters so cant use anything as delimiters.

Answer (score 36):

You can use a regular expression in the `search and replace`-dialog (`Ctrl`+`H`) that is [anchored](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to the end of the line:

```
.{13}$
```

Then replace it with nothing. And of course you could use a more expressive regex to match only dates in your particular format and nothing else.

Comment: This works totally fine, remember that the 13 in this expression can be changed to any number of characters you may need to trim.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said, use a regex search in the search and replace dialogue (ctrl + h) with the pattern the dates follow. Given your example this should do:

```
[A-Za-z]{3}\s(\d){1,2},\s?\d{4}$
```

Replace with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an alternative. You can also use the column edit mode.

Press `Alt` and `Left click` your mouse and move your mouse vertically over all the lines that you want to edit. Then you can just delete everything starting from that column.

EDIT. On second look I see that you mentioned the lines are of different length. So this might not work in your case. Anyways I will leave it as it is. Who knows it might come in handy later, or maybe for someone else.